# Aligning image bottom of div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I'm trying to format an image so it aligns to the bottom of a div. I put what I think is the relevant code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5KEyD/

```
<div id="main">
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px">
<div id="imageWrapper">
<img id="bottomImage" class="aligncenter" src="Bottom-Text.png" alt="Some Image" width="800" height="152" /></div>    </div></div> 

#main{width:800px; height: 200px; padding-right:40px; overflow:hidden; background-    color: #c0c0c0;}
#imageWrapper { position: relative; height: 152px; } /* height is for display purposes only */
#bottomImage { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }
```

What I need is for the image to align (centered) all the way at the bottom, with no extra grey space under it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Everything is okay. `#imageWrapper` has height 182px, image has height 182px. Image is positioned absolutely to bottom.

Comment: Set main's height same as #imageWrapper's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Amended webpage]

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="imageWrapper">
        <img id="bottomImage" class="aligncenter" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Bottom-Text.png" alt="Some Image" width="800" height="152">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because of using display: inline-block for div element. Inline-block rule always adds 5px margins to element. So if you remove it [the issue will be fixed](https://monosnap.com/image/aAidK7My68GnuQ4FBEL8ghgWWUXuSX). If you need that rule you can [add -5px bottom margin](https://monosnap.com/image/RBxilkZCJsU7LEyYpWZkBagjX0B9jZ).

Comment: Ohh, I had no idea inline-block added 5px margins. Very good to know! Thanks for the help!